# Problem in Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

/checkout/cart page is working properly without any product in the cart.
[image: Checkout Page without product]

But, when any product is added to cart, it shows nothing
[image: Checkout page with Product]

[View source] of the page is as follows :-
[image: Source of Checkout page with Product]

Pl. guide.

Comment: try clearing var and static files from pub and refresh the page.

Comment: Sometimes improper permission leads to this issue. Try giving 777 to var folder and refresh Magento cache and browser cache as well.

Comment: Tried after clearing files from pub but, no luck

Comment: Permission changed as suggested but, no change in page

Answer (score 0):

Can you check console, exception log for further debugging.